# Loading multiple results from ODBCDataAdapter doesn't load all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, odbc

I am using an ODBC driver to run an sql script with multiple select statements, and hence multiple result sets. The results that load into the dataset are not as expected.

Here is what the dataset looks like after filling with the DataAdapter:

```
ReportType                     CreatedDate            CountofFirmCreated
----------                     -----------            ------------------
Firms Created                  27/03/2023 12:00:00 am                 14
Firms Created                  28/03/2023 12:00:00 am                 15
Firms Created                  29/03/2023 12:00:00 am                 10
Firms Created                  30/03/2023 12:00:00 am                 20
Firms Created                  31/03/2023 12:00:00 am                 22
Firms Created                  1/04/2023 12:00:00 am                  24
Firms Created                  2/04/2023 12:00:00 am                  39
Firms Created                  3/04/2023 12:00:00 am                  40
Firms Created                  4/04/2023 12:00:00 am                  73
Firms Created                  5/04/2023 12:00:00 am                  91
Firms: Users Invited
Firms: Users Invited
Firms: Users Invited
Firms: Users Invited
Firms: Users Invited
Firms: Users Invited
Firms: Users Invited
Firms: Users Invited
Firms: Users Invited
Firms: Users Invited
```

As you can see, the first result set is loaded into the dataset as expected, but every result set after it only loads one of the three columns that are in the result. All of the result sets have three columns of data, but all have different column header names. There are 6 result sets in total. Is there anything wrong with my code that would cause this to happen? Here's my code:

```
$connectionString = "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=$servername;Database=$database;UID=$username;Password=$password;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"

# Create and open SQL connection
$connection = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()

# Create a SQL command object
$command = New-object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($script, $connection)

$ds = New-Object system.Data.DataSet

$adapter = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter $command
$adapter.FillSchema($ds, [System.Data.SchemaType]::Source)
$adapter.Fill($ds) | Out-Null
$ds.Tables
```

Comment: Try removing the Schema line and set what you get as results.  Also try outputting using following : $ds.Tables[0] | Format-List

Comment: @jdweng interesting, when I print out individual tables in the dataset, it works correctly. not sure why that is

Comment: A Dataset is 3-D containing Tables/Rows/Columns.  How to you display 3-D in only 2-D?